# How to add a rich control(not just MenuItem) for a applet like Rhythmbox

Tags: indicator, rhythmbox, application-development, applet

I want to write a small tools in the form of Applet, but not just a "applet".
I want to show a listview or anything in the applet, unfortunly it seems that ONLY Menu/MenuItem can be add into applet. 
But anyone using rhythmbox must use the "Previous||Pause||Next" button on the sound-applet
So can anyone have a solution to make such a control?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Something to go in the panel?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably talking about *indicators* and not *applets*. The available controls are very limited. Anything other than normal menu enties are provided by libido.